# QT export library to path defferent from DESTDIR

Tags: qt, qmake

I know using DESTDIR to specify export path, but I don't know how can I export the library file to path which is different from DESTDIR.
Like that:

```
 ---Build
  |---bin
  |    |---*.exe
  |    |---*.dll
  |---lib
  |    |---*.lib
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

QMake has a special, windows-only variable `DLLDESTDIR` which you can use to specify a different destination for the `.dll` itself. So to achieve what you want, point `DESTDIR` to the directory where everything *except* the DLL should end up, end `DLLDESTDIR` to the location for the DLL:

```
DESTDIR = lib
win32: DLLDESTDIR = bin
```

Comment: It's better to [add more context/explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) around code (as opposed to just having a code-only answer) as that makes the answer more useful.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) (Note: I'm not familiar with this domain, so this answer may actually be simple enough to make an explanation, and thus downvotes, unnecessary. You may still want to add an explanation to prevent more NAA/VLQ flags.)